# Using Eagle: How do I have separate parts in the schematic, but a single socket in the board?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I have a schematic that looks like this:

[image: Pro micro connected to a MAX7219 with 16 LEDs and also 16 SPST switches]

In reality, this is basically 16 SPST switches with LEDs in them.

What I would like on the PCB is for each pair of switch+LED to end in something to which I can solder something like this:

[image: 4 pin jst connector (I think that's what it's called)]

<sub>4 pin JST connector (I think that's what it's called)</sub>

How would I go about doing that? (Right now the board view displays LEDs and standard prototyping momentary switches.)

Comment: I don't know Eagle, but in general, you are looking for a "device with multiple symbols". Logic ICs commonly have multiple symbols (you can place each gate separately in the schematic), so PCB software tends to support it. You might need to create your own device for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

> *What I would like on the pcb, is for each pair of switch+led to end in
> something to which I can solder something*

The simplest option is to redraw your schematic using the symbol and footprint for the pin header that you have indicated.

You are choosing to use a pin header and it's a pin header that is soldered to your PCB. In other words, the switches and the LEDs are NOT fundamentally part of the PCB assembly any more so, just use the pin header AND, if your schematic looks confusing symbolically, there is absolutely nothing stopping you from making a pin header symbol that looks like a switch and an LED combined coming out to four pins. It won't affect the footprint of course.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy says, draw the connections to the socket. You can then draw a matching plug, connected to LED and switch, next to the first socket (don't assign PCB symbols to these parts since they won't be on the PCB!) to show the connectivity.

There's no need to repeat the plug/switch/LED assembly, it's just clutter (assuming the sockets are arranged neatly on the schematic)